# Writing PyQGIS code to select items in line layer by length?

Tags: pyqgis

I have been trying to write a short code to select items in a line layer that are longer than 2000m, but I don't have much luck at the moment now.

```
layer=iface.activeLayer()
selected_fid=[]
lenth=[]
for f in layer.getFeatures():
    selected_fid.append(f.id())
    lenth.append( f.geometry().length())

for i in range(0,len(lenth)):
    if lenth[i]>2000:
        print i
```

This is what I have, and the first thing I notice is that the len function does not work in QGIS python console, I am not sure why. It gives me an error as below:

```
len(lenth)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Additionally, I am not sure how to set those items using setSelectedFeatures function.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Seems to work fine for me, which QGIS version are you using? Did you select a line layer before running your code?

Comment: Hi Joseph, I use QGIS 2.18.26, I am certain that I've selected the layer I am working on as the first for-loop worked fine, but the second for-loop did not work.

Comment: Are there items stored in the list if you just type `lenth`? Maybe your lines do not exceed 2000m?

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, don't forget that if you want to work in metres, you need to make sure your line layer is in a projected co-ordinate reference system, and that the layer is selected (active) in the table of contents.

Then try this:

```
lyr = iface.activeLayer()
fids = []
for f in lyr.getFeatures():
    if f.geometry().length() > 2000:
        fids.append(f.id())
if fids:
    lyr.selectByIds(fids)
else:
    print("No features match this condition")
```

Edit: I see in in your comments you are using QGIS 2.18

**For QGIS 2.18,** just change:

```
lyr.selectByIds(fids)
```

to:

```
lyr.setSelectedFeatures(fids)
```

This will select all line features longer than 2000m, but will also tell you if no features matching that condition are found (i.e. the fids list is empty).

Tested in QGIS 3.4.1 python console.

[image]